# how to properly handle a file upload in wicket

Tags: wicket, solaris, wicket-1.5

I have a file upload page that takes a file and parses it.

**Order of Events**

1. user uploads file
2. uploaded file gets copied
3. copied file gets it's encoding checked, with [CPDetector](http://cpdetector.sourceforge.net/%20CPDetector)
4. determined encoding from the copied file is used to parse the original uploaded file

   - `FileNotFoundException` on Solaris Test Server during `BufferedReader` creation.
5. copied file is deleted
6. uploaded file is parsed/verified
7. parsed data is saved to a database
8. uploaded file is deleted (I can't remember if I'm doing this or Tomcat is.)

The Whole process works on my Windows 7 workstation. As noted above it does not work on my Solaris Test Server. Something(I Suspect Tomcat) is deleting the uploaded file before I can finish parsing it.

I've watched the directory during the process and an uploaded file does indeed get created, but it lasts less than a second before being deleted.  Also It's supposed to go into `/opt/tomcat/` but seems be getting created in the `/var/opt/csw/tomcat6/temp/` directory instead.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realize it's probably bad form to answer my own question like this but I wanted to leave this here in-case it helps someone else.

The Problem turned out to be How I was accessing the files.

I had hard-coded file paths, for windows, and Database loaded ones for the test server.
I switched those to using `System.getProperty("catalina.home")+"/temp/" + filename`
I'm also copying the temp file a second time so I end up with:

**Order of Events *(changes are in bold)***

1. user uploads file
2. uploaded file gets copied
3. copied file gets it's encoding checked, with *CPDetector*
4. **uploaded file gets copied again to ensure a copy survives to be parsed**
5. determined encoding from the copied file is used to parse the original uploaded file
6. copy used for encoding detection is deleted
7. **copy for parse is parsed/verified**
8. parsed data is saved to a database
9. **parsed file is deleted.**
10. uploaded file is deleted (I'm not sure if I'm doing this or Tomcat is.)